# Clear apple music history

Tags: music, apple-music

I have added some songs on Apple Music for my sister. But even now after I have removed then they still appear on the for you tab. How can I clear my history in apple music. Reset it. I know I can choose different genres but after that some of my sister music still appear on the four you tab. Especially on the iPhone where I can scroll down to it.